# Using Neo4j 2.1.2 database with Neo4j 2.1.3 fails to start

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to copy over a database that I've been using with Neo4j 2.1.2 to a new machine that I upgraded from Neo4j 2.0.3 to Neo4j 2.1.3. Seems like it is coming down to `Expected 'NeoStore v0.A.0' but file is version 'NeoStore v0.A.3'.` but I don't know how to fix that.

Here's what I did:

On my old server:

- Shut down my 2.1.2 server using `bin/neo4j stop`
- Copied the graph.db directory to my new server

On my new server:

- Delete the existing graph.db directory
- Ran `apt-get install neo4j` to upgrade the new server from 2.0.3 to 2.1.3
- Server started successfully without warnings
- Deleted the newly created graph.db directory
- Copied my existing graph.db directory into the data directory for 2.1.3
- Ran `chown` to change the owner of the files to neo4j
- Attempted to start the server using `sudo service neo4j-service start`
- Also tried setting `allow_store_upgrade=true` but that had no effect

Here is the console output that I get:

```
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [9107]... waiting for server to be ready... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
```

Here is the error logged in messages.log:

```
2014-08-06 19:13:13.103+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: 
Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@3bf17f92' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. 
Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@c3e122' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. 
Please see attached cause exception.: 'neostore' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NeoStore v0.A.0' but file is version 'NeoStore v0.A.3'.
2014-08-06 19:13:13.104+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started
```

And here is the console.log output:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
11:21:18,697 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:21:18,697 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
11:21:18,698 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar!/logback.xml]
11:21:18,699 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
11:21:18,699 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar!/logback.xml]
11:21:18,699 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.1.3.jar!/logback.xml]
11:21:18,725 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@2d3d0953 - URL [jar:file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
11:21:18,782 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:21:18,786 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
11:21:18,795 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
11:21:18,822 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:21:18,890 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
11:21:18,890 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
11:21:18,891 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:21:18,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@22f3f59 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

11:21:19.099 [main] INFO  o.n.s.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer - Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
```

Any tips to get this running?  I've actually never successfully copied a database to a new server running a new Neo4j version and had it actually work so I'm clearly using the wrong process.  The 2.1.3 server starts fine if I let it create a new empty database.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out all references to 2.0.3.jar in /usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/ -- make sure that there is only 2.1.3.

It looks like from your logs that your /neo4j/system/lib directories were merged together and contain incongruous jar files. Those jar files contain some meta data from compilation that could cause some conflicting issues.

And as always, backup your data store files before migrating.